# swift add element in a array of dictionary nested in a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, nested, updates

I have the following code :

```
var TabActions: Dictionary<String, Array<Dictionary<String, String>>> = [:]

TabActions = ["EVENT1" : ["TARGET1" : "ACTION1"], ["TARGET2" : "ACTION2"]]
```

I want to add ["TARGET3" : "ACTION3"] to the list but I can't figure how to do this. I've tried :

```
TabActions["EVENT1"] = [["TARGET3" : "ACTION3"]]
```

but it replaces the value instead of adding it and all other attempts end up with an error

What would be the best syntax to do this ?

Comment: `TabActions` should be `tabActions` - instances lower case - Classes/Struc Definition upper case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do really need a dictionary of arrays of dictionaries as presented, then Antonio's answer is correct, append will do the job:

```
var TabActions: Dictionary<String, Array<Dictionary<String, String>>> = [:]
TabActions = ["EVENT1" : [["TARGET1" : "ACTION1"], ["TARGET2" : "ACTION2"]]]

TabActions["EVENT1"]?.append(["TARGET3" : "ACTION3"])
```

On the other hand if you can get by with a simpler dictionary of dictionaries you just need to do:

```
var TabActions: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> = [:]       
TabActions = ["EVENT1" : ["TARGET1" : "ACTION1", "TARGET2" : "ACTION2"]]

TabActions["EVENT1"]?["TARGET3"] = "ACTION3"
```

Comment: Thanks. In your second proposition (without the Array) how to do if the first key (EVENT1) does not exist if I want the creation of both the key and the nested dictionary elements ("TARGET3", "ACTION3") associated to this key ?

Comment: Good point, you need to check if there is an existing dictionary for a given key:   `if let targets = TabActions["EVENT2"] {
            TabActions["EVENT2"]?["TARGET3"] = "ACTION3"
        } else {
            TabActions["EVENT2"] = ["TARGET3" : "ACTION3" ]
        }`

Answer (score 0):

The `TabActions` dictionary contains array values - and to append to an array you use the `append` method:

```
TabActions["EVENT1"]?.append(["TARGET3": "ACTION3"])
```

Note that if the `EVENT1` key is not found, no addition takes place.

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer ! What would I do in the case the first key does not exist as the append won't do anything as you said ?